# Как переключать inputmask?

Tags: javascript, input, inputmask

подскажите пожалуйста как выключать маску, когда пользователь вводит в инпут не цифру? Сейчас стоит маска для телефона и inputmask не пропускает ничего кроме цифр, задача стоит чтобы в поле могли вводить как телефон так и email, в зависимости от того что введено, включать маску для телефона или нет.

Comment: ищите regexp для нужных вам значений, если ввод подходит под regexp, включать маску, нет - искать под другие вводы маску, пока нужную не найдете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеет смысл не выключать маску, а наоборот включать, если пользователь вводит число:

```js
$('input').on('keyup',function(e){
  if(!isNaN($(this).val()) && e.keyCode != 8) {
    $(this).inputmask({"mask": "+7 (999) 999-9999"});
  }
});
$('input').on('focusout',function(){
  $(this).inputmask('remove');
})
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/5.0.6/jquery.inputmask.min.js"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <input type="text">
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы)